# firebase-collection : input value only updates first keystroke

Tags: firebase, polymer

I have a master-detail scenario. I'm using [paper-datatable by David Mulder](https://github.com/David-Mulder/paper-datatable) for my user-list. Data is populated through firebase collection
When tapping a row, a paper-dialog pops up with the details of the selected user. 
When trying to edit a field, updating at firebase stops after one keystroke.

What am I missing?

```
<dom-module id="user-list">
    <template>
        <style>
        :host {
            @apply(--layout-vertical);
        }

        #editDialog {
          min-width: 500px;
        }
        </style>
        <firebase-collection location="https://<FIREBASE_APP>.firebaseio.com/users" data="{{users}}"></firebase-collection>

        <paper-dialog id="editDialog" entry-animation="scale-up-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation" with-backdrop>
            <div>
                <paper-input value="{{selectedUser.name}}" label="Name" class="flex"></paper-input>
                <paper-input value="{{selectedUser.username}}" label="Username" class="flex"></paper-input>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <paper-button dialog-confirm autofocus>Ok</paper-button>
            </div>
        </paper-dialog>

        <paper-datatable id="datatable" selected-item="{{selectedUser}}" selectable on-row-tap="_onDetail" data="{{users}}">
            <div no-results>
                Loading or no more items...
            </div>
            <paper-datatable-column header="Name" property="name" type="String" sortable style="min-width: 160px"></paper-datatable-column>
            <paper-datatable-column header="Username" property="username" type="String" sortable style="min-width: 40px"></paper-datatable-column>
        </paper-datatable>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'user-list',

        behaviors: [
            Polymer.NeonAnimatableBehavior
        ],

        properties: {
            type: String,
            selectedUser: {
              type: Object,
              notify: true
            },
            users: {
                type: Array,
                notify: true
            },
            animationConfig: {
                value: function() {
                    return {
                        'entry': {
                            name: 'fade-in-animation',
                            node: this
                        },
                        'exit': {
                            name: 'fade-out-animation',
                            node: this
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        _onDetail: function() {
            var dialog = document.getElementById('editDialog');
            if (dialog) {
                dialog.open();
            }

        }
    })
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `firebase-collection` isn't currently meant to be used in this way, it's more of a view into a Firebase location with data that's in an *array-like* structure.  Although with the exception that you can add/delete new items but not update existing ones. See https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/firebase-element?active=firebase-collection.

That said, each item in the collection has a  `__firebaseKey__` property that you could use to directly update that item in firebase.